# jquery - everything inside variable (div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a reference to a div coming through into a function and I want to reference everything inside the div (to unbind all clicks for everything inside the div). I have something like

```
 $el.children().off();
```

I am trying to emulate something like this:

```
$("#myDiv *").off();
```

However I Would like to use the variable $el that I have here, so something like this

```
 $el *.off();
```

Is there a way around this in jquery? thanks!

Comment: there are several ways to do so. please post your code where you do the binding.

Answer (score 2):

```
$el.children().unbind();
```

should do the trick

Comment: [`.unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) is succeeded by [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) in jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

```
$el.find('*').off();
```

Documentation for `.find`: http://api.jquery.com/find/

---

The [context parameter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) has also been mentioned, but according to its docs:

> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
>   so `$( "span", this )` is equivalent to  `$( this ).find( "span" )`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the context parameter: `$('*', el)` will select everything inside the element (or jQuery collection) `el`